# How to provide seller with order details Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am creating a very basic online store that allows users to buy and customize certain products. I have gotten the payment system working using Stripe, and all that is left to do is provide the seller with a place to view the completed orders (which should contain Shipping Address, order configuration, etc).

I expect that this app will receive very, very low traffic (it's more for fun than anything), so I do not need a super robust admin system. I thought it would actually be sufficient to pass order information to stripe as metadata, and have the seller view the order information on stripe. However, a potential problem I see is that there might be more data than the metadata limit (20 key/value pairs, 500 val limits). Would it be better to create an admin system on my side (using webhooks to notify the application when the payment has been processed)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe is really only meant to handle the payments part of the equation. The order part is normally handled on top of Stripe (either in your own system or some third party), with that system linking order ids to charge ids.

Having your own order admin page would normally make more sense in the Stripe model, since Stripe only stores the amount charged and not much more.

Also unless you're doing subscriptions, no need to wait for a webhook. The Create Charge API is synchronous so you'll know when the payment was processed instantly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last 2 sentences? I set up my project with Stripe Checkout, so my chargers controller looks almost exactly like this: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails

My order model has an order status (ie. 1 for 'In Progress', 2 for 'Completed'). I would like update this status when Im sure the payment has gone through. Would it be valid to update the status at the bottom of the create method in the charges controller?

Comment: Yeah so when you call Stripe::Charge.create you know whether or not the charge went through as soon as the function returned. If the function returned successfully, a charge was created, if not it throws an error.